# i just wanna ask about "Resource.Id does not contain for..." in xamarin visual studio error CS0117

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I tried to make a simple list from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHvY1DUxzfo&list=PLCuRg51-gw5VqYchUekCqxUS9hEZkDf6l&index=3
and get CS0117 error saying it can't find the txtName Id from my source.

but, when I tried to compile the project, the project ran smoothly without any problems. is this an error from VS itself or is there really an error from my source code?

Build and rebuild project solution

---

ListViewAdapter.cs

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View row = convertView;

            if(row == null)
            {
                row = LayoutInflater.From(_context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.listview_row, null, false);
            }

            TextView txtName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtName);
            txtName.Text = _items[position];

            return row;
        }
```

listview_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="Name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

does anyone here know how to solve this problem? or just ignore it?
Thanks

Comment: try rebuild the xamarin project.

Comment: I have tried Build and Rebuild project and solution, but the error still appears.

Comment: try bruno's answer, I tried same earlier and it was working, might work for you too

Comment: ah, yes it's work... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is must likely a Intelissense error, or just the Resource file not being regenerated.

you can delete bin / obj folders, and edit an .axml file, and rebuild the solution.

If all runs smoothly, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: This works, Thanks... will this method have any impact/error in the future?

Comment: and don't know which .axml file should i edit. i just saw my .xml file..so i just deleted the bin and obj folder.

Comment: You can make a simple enter, just to force the regenrations of the Resource file. And will have no impact in the future.(Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it helped you :D)

Comment: Sure bro xD...Thanks for your help.